# POST binary data in IE8

Tags: ajax, post, internet-explorer-8, arrays

I am trying to POST raw data of 512 bytes to an Arduino with an Ethernet shield from Internet Explorer 8.  If you don't already know, an Arduino is a very small microcontroller with a VERY limited amount of RAM (SRAM), therefore neither Base64 nor URL encoding the data is an option or the stack will overflow.

I need to send this data very quickly in very short intervals (somewhere between 100ms and 250ms). No more, no less than 512 bytes of raw, un-encoded, unprocessed, binary data from IE8 (IE8 because IE9+ is not available for Windows XP) inside one POST request body.

This code works in FireFox

```
function PostDMXData(evt)
{
    var buff=new ArrayBuffer(512);
    var bytesArray=new Uint8Array(buff);
    for(var i=0;i<512;i++)
    {
        bytesArray[i]=DMXData[i];
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: "dmxdata.php",
       type: "POST",
       async: true,
       error: function(a,b,c){alert(c);},
       complete: function(a,b)
       {
        if(evt){evt();}
       },
       contentType: "application/octet-stream",  
       data: bytesArray,
       processData: false
    });
    delete buff;
    delete bytesArray;
}
```

But not in IE8.  `alert(c)` inside the error function displays "Error: The parameter is incorrect."  Using a non-minimized jQuery I found that it's an exception being generated by the XMLHttpRequest object on `.send(...)` itself.

I've tried using 2 different polyfills/shims for the Uint8Array data type that I found referenced here on StackOverflow for a number of related questions but it seems none of these are compatible.

Should I continue looking for another Uint8Array shim, give up on Ajax, or should I try something else with Ajax/jQuery?

Comment: Both IE8 and Windows XP are discontinued. Please come back to modern world.

Comment: @Raptor https://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+XP+market+share&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8